# Did Emanuel Lasker write a book declaring that Germany had to win World War I if civilization were to be saved?

Tags: world-war-one, germany, book, biography

Emanuel Lasker, the second chess world champion, was a very interesting person. I read [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20091028083454/http://www.geocities.com/SiliconValley/Lab/7378/lasker.htm) that

> During World War I, Lasker […] invested all of his money in
>   German war bonds. At the end of the war, he had lost all his money and
>   savings. During that period, he wrote a book declaring that Germany
>   had to win the war if civilization were to be saved.

However, I was unable to find any other reference to the existence of such a book. For instance, the [German Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanuel_Lasker) about Lasker mentions no book published by him during the war and the first book he published after the war (*Die Philosophie des Unvollendbar*, Leipzig 1919) seems to be a book about Philosophy. So, was such book ever written?

Comment: Most of the sites I found seem to reference a version of [this profile](http://billwall.phpwebhosting.com/articles/Emanuel_Lasker.htm) by Bill Wall as their source. Wall himself doesn't cite a source for that claim. He does, however, have a presence on Twitter (@billwallchess) which might allow you to ask him directly...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's likely not a book *per se*, but a brochure, of which he published several during the war.

The most likely candidate would be the pamphlet ["Die Selbsttäuschung unserer Feinde", Berlin, 1916](https://books.google.de/books/about/Die_Selbstt%C3%A4uschung_unserer_Feinde.html?id=0D20kgEACAAJ&redir_esc=y). (On the self delusions of our enemies)

Sadly, the [Emanuel Lasker Gesellschaft](https://www.lasker-gesellschaft.de/) should have this, but their site is currently "under construction".

[Secondary](https://de.chessbase.com/post/ein-weltmeisterdrama) mentions are in some [books](https://books.google.de/books?id=q5FdDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78).

*Nota bene* he was by far not unique among German intellectuals to pit (German) culture against (Western) civilization. More about this in [Making Sense of the War (Germany)](https://encyclopedia.1914-1918-online.net/article/making_sense_of_the_war_germany).

That pamphlet seems to be quite rare now. If you are really dedicated to read the original, a [few libraries still have it](http://www.worldcat.org/title/selbsttauschung-unserer-feinde/oclc/405512568).